# Windows Storage Spaces incorrectly reporting drive space

Tags: windows-10, powershell, raid, storage-spaces

I recently set up a Storage Space on Windows 10 Pro for workstations.

I am using a pcie nvme card that holds 4 drives, I want to stripe these into a RAID 0 array. I used the storage space GUI in the control panel and found that the performace was not great.

I did my research and found out that to configure the storage space in more detail you need to use Powershell and adjust **`-NumberOfColumns 2`**, where 2 being the number of ssds in the array.

**Full commands below:**

- **command 1 - create the pool**

```
$PhysicalDisks = (Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $True)

New-StoragePool -FriendlyName RAID -StorageSubsystemFriendlyName "Windows Storage*" -PhysicalDisks $PhysicalDisks
```

- **Command 2 Create the storage volume**

```
New-VirtualDisk -StoragePoolFriendlyName RAID -FriendlyName MEDIA_RAID -ResiliencySettingName Simple -UseMaximumSize -NumberOfColumns 2
```

Having done this I have my expected performance on the storage pool.

However, an issue has come up where Windows is incorrectly reporting the amount of space used on the pool. Has anyone else come by this before and is there any issue/fix?

Within the storage spaces GUI it says the pool is almost full, each drive is reported 99% full. However, in Explorer the drive is reported empty, which is correct.

This issue only appears when using the PowerShell interface to create the storage space, if done completely through the GUI the information is reported correctly, but I do not get accurate speeds on the pool.

See screenshot for illustration:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Stupid question what should the size of your RAID be?  You are aware of a single drive fails in a RAID 0 all data on the RAID is lost?

Comment: It is 2x 1.9TB Corsiar MP510, so the size of the pool is correct. Yes very aware of the redundancy issue, this is a working RAID for fast media storage and transcoding. Several copies of source media are made on separate drives.

Comment: How many disks and what size are supposed to be in that pool ? For 2x 1.9 it looks correct, but in the question you say 4 drives and you don't mention any sizes. We are not psychic. Please explain what you expected to see. (PS: You can edit your question to supply more information.)

Comment: The issue is not the size of the pool it is that it is being incorrectly reported, please see the screenshot at the bottom of my post. Storage spaces sees the pool as full, but expolorer reports it empty as it is. I will review my initial question to make this clearer